# How to fill "waveInGetDevCaps" function parameters in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm using the Window's API, in particular the 'WaveIn' functions. I want to know the format that my laptop's input audio device supports.

Therefore, I used the function "waveInGetDevCaps." This function call , once called, fills in a WAVEINCAPS structure with the information about the audio device.

This is my code so far:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);

    var
    wc : WAVEINCAPS;  // structure to be filled with audio device info

    begin
    waveInGetDevCaps(WAVE_MAPPER, &wc, sizeof(WAVEINCAPS));
    Showmessage (wc.dwFormats);  
    end;
```

However I keep getting an error: 
`"E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWaveInCapsA' and 'tagWAVEINCAPSA2"`

I would appreciate any help please.

Information on "waveInGetDevCaps" and "WAVEINCAPS" can be found:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator to take the address. You use `&` in C and C++. In Delphi the operator is `@`. This operator is documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#The_.40_Operator

In Delphi, `&` is used to [escape keywords](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Extended_Identifiers). It has no effect here, because `wc` is not a keyword, and is essentially ignored, treated as whitespace.

Replace `&` with `@` and your code will compile. Don't forget to check the return value of the function call for errors, as described in the function documentation.

The Delphi header translations introduce Pascal-case type names so instead of the `WAVEINCAPS` type it would be idiomatic to use the `TWaveInCaps` type.

Comment: Not that it's relevant, do you know why the '&' is just ignored?

Comment: @Sertac I just added an explanation, and then read your comment!

Comment: Thanks anyway. I don't understand though why I should use &Type instead of _Type, both doesn't really quite look like Type. Maybe required for library imports or such....

Comment: @Sertac For instance, if you are using RTTI serialization then you may need to do that to get the name to match the interface. I've never done it personally.

Comment: thanks a lot @DavidHeffernan However, when i try to view what the member of the structure is (via show message)... it shows me a number ? I expected something like WAVE_FORMAT_4M16 (from the structure's website link)?                                                                  Also, how can I view what the return value is? Or do I do this by using conditional statements to check  if it matches one of the expected returns?

Comment: `WAVE_FORMAT_4M16` is a numeric constant with value `0x00000400`. It should be defined in mmsystem. If not it's in the C++ header file from the SDK. Nothing in the system is going to translate from the numeric value back to the symbol.  You already know how functions work. `retval := SomeFunc(..._);`. Then compare retval to the success code stated in the docs.

Comment: @Sertac, the `&` syntax was introduced for .Net compatibility. When you import a .Net library, you don't get to choose new identifier names (as you would when importing a DLL or interface and manually declaring everything in a new unit). Thus, if an external .Net class has a member named `Begin`, that's what you have to call it in Delphi, too. To avoid the `begin` reserved word, you can write `&Begin`. Instead of an ampersand, you can also write fully qualified names, like `ObjectReference.Begin`.